# How can I start a java application with parameters using a pm2 config file?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm trying to start [graphhopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper) using `pm2`... `graphhopper` is a java application and the way I initiate it on the terminal is by going to its folder and entering the following command:

```
java -jar matching-web/target/graphhopper-map-matching-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml
```

This application works fine running from the command line, but I haven't succeeded on running it as a service with `pm2`. The config file I'm using is this one (`pm2 start config.json`):

```
{
    "apps":[
    {
        "name":"graphhopper",
        "cwd":".",
        "script":"/usr/bin/java",
        "args":[
            "-jar",
            "/home/myyser/graphhopper/map-matching/matching-web/target/graphhopper-map-matching-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
            "server",
            "config.yml"
        ],
        "log_date_format":"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
        "exec_interpreter":"",
        "exec_mode":"fork"
     }
   ]
}
```

I'm 100% sure that what I'm getting wrong here is the way I'm writing the `"server", "config.yml"` parameters... Looking into `pm2 logs graphhopper` I can see that those parameters are not being recognized at all... I've tried to tweak the way it's done as well but I didn't manage to figure out the right solution. I know how to start a java application using `pm2` with no parameters. But how can I do it with a java application that has parameters as in the case of `graphhopper`?

Comment: write a bash script . Include in bash CLI , the list of args above. ie the bash is a wrapper for java cli args.  Then just call that wrapper shell from the apps property in the json

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thanks!! Just the bash script was enough to solve my problem. After creating the script and giving it execution permission I can start my service using `pm2 start graphhopper.sh --name=graphhopper` . The file of my question turns out not being necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this issue can be solved by creating a bash script and running it with `pm2` instead of running directly the java application... The bash script used was the file `graphhopper.sh` as the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
java -jar matching-web/target/graphhopper-map-matching-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml
```

And to start it as a service with `pm2`:

```
pm2 start graphhopper.sh --name=graphhopper
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also run a fat jar directly in pm2 - use two dashes to separate the command args:

```
pm2 start java --  -jar matching-web/target/graphhopper-map-matching-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml
```

Comment: where is the config.yml

Answer (score 0):

Mine java app worked fine - just use 1 arg -  no array.

```
apps:
  - name : 'admin'
    script: '/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java'
    args:  '-jar ./wweevvAdmin/target/wweevvAdmin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    instances: '1'
    autorestart: true
```